# Azure functions: Move to poison blob without retry if a particular exception is thrown

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a blob triggered function, in which a data is deserialized from a Json string and then the further process are done and save the data to db.

My blob trigger function max retry is set as 5. Means if the blob process fails it will retry for 5 times and then move the blob to poison blob.

If the deserialization is failed, then there is no need to retry it for 5 times.
So, if the deserialzation exception is thrown I need to move the blob to poison blob without retry. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: you dais you have a blob trigger and then talking about queue ... do you have a storage queue or servicebus queue trigger ?

Comment: @Thomas.. My bad, I have edited the question. I have a storage-blob triggered function

Comment: when you say blob trigger, you mean eventgrid trigger targetting a blob storage ??

Comment: No, I am talking about blob triggered Azure Function

Comment: ooh, I did not know about that ;-) good to know :-) I think you have an answer from  @pawel-maga

Comment: Yes... Working on it. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in solution for such case afaik, but you can add an output binding to your poison queue and insert a message manually in the form described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---poison-blobs

> The queue message for poison blobs is a JSON object that contains the following properties:
>
> FunctionId (in the format .Functions.)
>
> BlobType ("BlockBlob" or "PageBlob")
>
> ContainerName
>
> BlobName
>
> ETag (a blob version identifier, for example: "0x8D1DC6E70A277EF")

```
[FunctionName("blobtrigger")]
public static async Task Run(ILogger log, ExecutionContext executionContext,
    [BlobTrigger("blobs/{name}")] Stream blob,
    [Queue("webjobs-blobtrigger-poison")] CloudQueue poisonQueue)
{
    try {
        // do something
        throw new JsonSerializationException();
    }
    catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
    {
        log.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        await poisonQueue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage()); // your message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way would be to set the `maxDequeueCount` to 1. Add the following to your **host.json** file :

```
"extensions": {
  "queues": {
      "maxDequeueCount": 1
  }
}
```

This effectively sets the max retries to 0 and a message is added to the poison blob queue as soon as an exception bubbles all the way up in your function.

The documentation is pretty confusing as the setting is within the queues section and doesn't look like it's related to the blob trigger.

I was able to find this from the WebJobs documentation though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/visual-studio/vs-storage-webjobs-getting-started-blobs#how-to-handle-poison-blobs

Comment: This would cause all errors to not retry, in which case you should just update your retry policy. The question was about dynamically skipping retries for specific exception types.